# calculate average based on 1 number only

Tags: java, math, data-structures

How to calculate percentage ( or average) when You have dividend but not deviser?

Comment: That last edit was really un-helpful.  I strongly suggest you roll back to edit 2.

Comment: "percentage (or average)" makes no sense. They are completely unrelated concepts.

Comment: So... correct me if I'm wrong: "I have a 3. I'd like to know the value of (3 / X) * 100 (percentage), or better: (3 + X) / 2 (average) without knowing X". I would say... 4, maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of values, and some of them figure into your average - or percentage - and some of them probably don't.  You are not expressing the problem clearly enough for anyone to be able to give you a meaningful answer.

A percentage represents a fraction, one value divided by another (multiplied by 100 to express it in percentage, but that's trivial and not part of the problem).  What is the value that represents 100%?  And what value are you trying to assign?  In what way do you think that the quantity of bonuses should affect the percentage?

Some possible answers:

The total bonus earned by an individual, as compared to her nominal salary.  If she earns $50k and her bonus is $20K, that is 20/50 *100 = 40%.

The total bonus earned by an individual, as compared to all the bonuses given out that year.  If she received the same $20K, but the company gave out $100K in bonuses, then the percentage is 20/100 * 100 = 20%.

The most recent bonus earned by an individual, as compared to all bonuses awarded to her this year.  If she got $5K for her last bonus, and the total was $20, that's 5/20 * 100 = 25%.

We really don't have enough information to go on; it could be any of these, or something entirely different.  It is entirely possible to have a percentage value greater than 100%.

Comment: It is entirely possible to have a percentage value greater than 100%. - Possible or Impossible?

Comment: Possible.  For instance, if the employee's base salary was 50K and she earned 75K in bonuses, that's 75/50 *100 = 150%.  It's just simple division.

Comment: Hi Carl, you understood my question :). When bonus increases than the original pay, it shows above 100% value. Any solution? How can we restrict this? I also simplified my question to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @Tweety: it's not a problem; that's what percentage *is*.  No solution is possible, because it's just the nature of percentage.  The *problem* is perceiving percentages in excess of 100% as a problem - it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The average of one value is that value (Total number=1).

But this probably means I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't mind the joke... but I'm a little insulted that someone upvoted it! ;-)

Comment: I think the upvote of the joke implies that the question is incomprehensible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the number of years, you need to know something else about the range of bonuses possible. i.e. does it have to be a whole number between 15 - 25%.  However, this is largely guessing.

To get an average, you need a total and a count. BTW: In your case you want the geometric average, but you need to know the same things.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a list of numbers, showing percentage values means you need to compute the total and then see how much of the total each of them is:
For instance, if you have 110, 110, 110, you'll have a total of 330 and each of the values will be shown as 110/330 = 0.33 = 33% of the total.

Comment: In case of a single value, the total will always be equal to the value and the percentage will always be 100% (no more no less).

Comment: What do you need to display (again) ? Percentage for each bonus or a single percentage value per employee ? If it's the latter, it will be percentage of what ?

Comment: "What about 330 total amount percentage ?" That will be 100% -- the full pie, if you see it as a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

> In addition, if I have three decimal
>   values 120, 4420, and 230. How can I
>   get a number less than 1 that
>   represent the average of these 3
>   values?

You cannot.  The average of those 3 numbers will be (120 + 4420 + 230) / 3.  That will never be less than one.  Maybe you are confused about what average means?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific or give an example. But I will give an answer based off of what I THINK you mean.

You cannot find the average of one lone number. If you were saying a temperature of 125 degrees every hour you could do it, The answer would obviously be 125. It is the closest thing that I can think of to what you are asking. You need to be more specific or the problem cannot be done. Otherwise use the simple formula: Sum/Number of integers. Also known as the mean. So that would be 125/1, which is still 125.